# When did speakers of Semitic languages reach northern Levant and Syria?

Tags: historical-linguistics, reference-request, semitic-languages

Is there an approximate date when speakers of semitic languages reached northern Levant and Syria? I understand that from the linguistic material this can be difficult, but I look for litterature (if any) that brings a hypothesis to the table.

Comment: Maybe you can find more sources if you look for the history of semitic people. As far as I remember, Akkadians had territories in some parts of Syria. Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natufian_culture

Comment: @kabraxis Thank you! I am aware of all these, I am just looking for somekind of analysis or hypothesis on this issue. It's a call for sources.

Comment: Aramaeans got to Syria in the 10th century BC.

Comment: It's packed in a box somewhere, so I can't check; but I suspect that _The Semitic Languages_, edited by Robert Hetzron has answers to this.